# Send DELETE request to an API endpoint using Nestful Sinatra

Tags: api, sinatra, http-delete

I want to send a DELETE request to an external API endpoint in a controller of my Sinatra application using nestful gem. I want to delete an event by sending a DELETE request to an endpoint of TeamSnap API. I have defined the following route in controller:

```
delete '/events/:id' do
  delete 'https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/events/76674685'
end
```

When the API endpoint is hit with `delete` action, I get the following error:

`*** "Delete" argument "endpoint" needs to be a number`

If I send a get request to the API endpoint, I get the correct response. The get request I am using is given below:

```
get '/events/:id' do
  get 'https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/events/76674685'
end
```

Can anyone confirm how can we send the DELETE request in the controller and what I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Solved]:** I sent a DELETE request through Nestful using the following commands:

```
delete '/events/:id' do
  request = Nestful::Request.new(endpoint, options)
  request.method = 'delete'
  response = request.execute
end
```

In the above piece of code, `endpoint` is "https://api.teamsnap.com/v3/events/EVENT_ID" and `options` is a hash which contains "Content-Type" and "Authorization" headers.

Comment: there were no anwers or comments to this. But it is very helpful. Thanks for posting your solution.